# Can google analytic API provide all info of all pages of a website?

Tags: google-analytics-api

I am new to Google Analytics. I would like to get all information (Unique and Total Visitors, Redirecting URL etc)  of a Profile, which has url like  **www.someurl.com/profile/unique_profile_id**

So I can easily have unique url for each profile, but as I am new to this. I don't know where to start.

API docs is good but confused where to start. If some can suggest small source of getting started with what i mentioned it will be very helpful.
Thanks in advance.

I come up with this query, but still I am not understanding ga:ids.  This ga:id is for my home page **www.mydomain.com**

```
https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?ids=ga%3A90283827&start-date=30daysAgo&end-date=yesterday&metrics=ga%3Apageviews%2Cga%3AuniquePageviews
```

Let's suppose my site have 1000 user and their profile has url as I mentioned above. So what will be ids for that each profile to query.

Comment: ids: is the id for the Google Analytics view you want to request data from.  There will probably only be one.  Unless you have more then one view set up in google analytics.

Comment: Welcome to stack: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  We are here to help you fix your problems.   Why don't you try a few examples from the documentation you spoke of then come back and ask questions relating to the code you have created.

Comment: do anyone have answer or simple approach to do what i want to do. How to get analytics info of particular page ?  Please @DaImTo  how can make an API request from some page of my website to get info of that page info. It will be very help full for me if you give your 1 minute.

Comment: Use the Google Analytics reporting api show us what you have tried we will help you fix any problems

Comment: [GA Testing Link](http://sarkaarikaam.com/schoolwiser/public/checkGA)  This is where i have put code from docs of JS API. Now As far as i can understand that it is giving result related to the user who has just logged in. What i want is that how can i access data of each page that is currently available in my site.

Comment: check [This Screenshot] ( https://www.dropbox.com/s/6g0dvzl1to5pr3b/chc.png?dl=0 ) this is what i get when i sign in with my account

Comment: Very good that is exactly what you should get.  the API returns the data to you in Json format.  Its working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are miss understanding how the Google Analytics API works.   The api returns raw data back from Google Analytics in the form of Json.   It will be up to you to format that data.

> What I want is that how can I access data of each page that is
>   currently available in my site.

I sugest you look at [ga:pagepath](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=page_tracking&jump=ga_pagepath) by adding this dimension you will be able to request data by the page.  for example pagepath, sessions will give you the number of sessions by the page path.  You may want to try testing using the [query explorer](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/) so that you can get back only the data you need.

Comment: Actually I already figured same solution after reading code of a WordPress theme which is doing what i want. BTW thanks for your answer. **One more Que**   what about authentication . Should i use my own site authentication or google authentication necessary.

Comment: If you only want to access your own data, look into a service account. If you are going to be accessing other peoples data then you will need to use Oauth2 and ask them to authorize your application.

Comment: @DalmTo  I have two more question. I have created service account and downloaded json file and from admin section added user with email in json file. Now what changes i have to make in my JS code which is requesting API.  **Second Que**  Should i use PHP library or JS function. I just want to reveal unique and page views of each user and nothing else that is why i am thinking to use JS in place of including whole PHP library.

Comment: You cant use a Service account with JavaScript.  This is my php tutorial. http://www.daimto.com/google_service_account_php/

Comment: Oh thanks. Finally i got clear picture of analytics API. Now I can proceed.